# Android application: How to detect beacon without hardcoding the UUID of a specific beacon?

Tags: android, uuid, altbeacon

I am working on an Android application which tries to connect to nearby beacons.

Currently, this is how I am trying to detect a beacon. However, I want to detect multiple such beacons in the vicinity without specifically mentioning the UUID of it.

`beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("01122334-4556-6778-899a-abbccd2993a8", null, null, null));`

How can I do this? I tried to look up multiple threads on stack overflow, but I couldn't really get any specific answer for this. It would be really helpful if I can get a documentation or a link to follow on this. I am sort of stuck on this stage of my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("any-identifier", null, null, null));
```

The first parameter is just a reference string you can use top stop monitoring at a later time.  Passing a region with the same reference string will stop monitoring for that region.  Your code probably works as you want as-is, as any reference string value is allowed and has no affect on the beacons detected.

Comment: Thank you for the answer above. I have an additional question, once we detect a beacon in a region, how can we get its UUID? Is it possible to get UUID of a beacon after it is detected?

Comment: For that you need to use both startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion and startRangingBeaconsInRegion at the same time